# kubectl create configmap - options to remove file names from output configmap when generateing using --file-name option

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks, configmap

I am using kubectl create configmap command as follows:

```
kubectl create configmap config-multi-yaml-files --from-file=templates/1template.yaml --from-file=apps/app1.yaml --from-file=app2/app2.yaml  --dry-run=true -o yaml > output.yaml
```

The resultant configmap do have file names (app1.yaml, app2.yaml) like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  app1.yaml: |-
  groups:
  - name: sample
    rules:
    - alert: alert
```

How can I use this command so that I do have a configmap from multiple yamls, but do not have the respective file names in the resultant configmap.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to store key value pair inorder to acces the data from a config map
why you would need to remove the key??

Comment: because all values are unique and on top level we are adding single key. so want to remove intermediate file names that act as key.

Comment: --from-file=[]: Key file can be specified using its file path, in which case file basename will be used as
configmap key, or optionally with a key and file path, in which case the given key will be used.  Specifying a directory
will iterate each named file in the directory whose basename is a valid configmap key.


``` you can iterate over the generated file and remove file by writing a program or manualy```

Comment: no progress but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you will have to use keys in order to make it work. But here is an example of what you could do:

```
kubectl create configmap config-multi-yaml-files --from-file <(cat templates/1template.yaml) --from-file <(cat apps/app1.yaml) --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

That way the keys would be numbers: 11, 12, 13...

So you will not have to use file names in your `ConfigMap` but keys will have to be used.